# Discord.JS Command Issue

Tags: javascript, bots, discord.js

I've been working on this command (that I have a problem with) where when the user says `u?hi`, the bot replies before putting you in a set. You are then put in a timeout for 20 seconds, and while you are in the timeout, if you type `u?hi`, the bot replies `gotta wait x seconds`. When the timeout ends, they can type `u?hi` and the cycle keeps going.

However, I've encountered a problem. In my code, after doing `u?hi`, I get put in a timeout (just like how I planned). However, while in the timeout, if I type `u?hi` while lets say 1 seconds into the timeout, instead of the bot saying `gotta wait 19 more seconds`, the bot says `gotta wait 19 more seconds` and then starts counting down all the way to 0. Here's what I mean (Screenshot):

[image: Bot is counting all the way down]

> Here's my code:

```
const intervalSet = new Set();

bot.on("message", msg => {
  let args = msg.content.substring(prefix.length).split(" ");
  switch (args[0]) {
    case "hi":

      var interval = 20;
      var intervalID;

      if (intervalSet.has(msg.author.id)) {
        intervalID = setInterval(() => {
          interval -= 1;
          if (interval !== 0 && args[0] === 'hi') {
            msg.channel.send(`gotta wait ${interval} more seconds`);
          }
          if (interval === 0) {
            clearInterval(intervalID);
            msg.channel.send(`Ended`);
            intervalSet.delete(msg.author.id);
          }
        }, 1000);
      } else {
        intervalSet.add(msg.author.id);
        msg.channel.send("heyy");
      }
  }
});
```

I've tried moving the

```
 if (interval !== 0 && args[0] === 'hi') {
            msg.channel.send(`gotta wait ${interval} more seconds`);
          }
```

part to other places of the code and changing it up but nothing seems to work. What can I do about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes that's normal with your code. What you need to do is to create a map, named `cooldown`. User IDs will be linked with times, so you'll be able to calculate for how long the user is in cooldown.

Here is an update of your code:

```js
const cooldown = new Map();

bot.on("message", msg => {
  let args = msg.content.substring(prefix.length).split(" ");
  switch (args[0]) {
    case "hi":

      var interval = 20000; // use milliseconds instead of seconds
      var intervalID;

      if (cooldown.has(msg.author.id)) {
        let cooldownTime = Date.now() - cooldown.get(msg.author.id);
        let timeToWait = (interval-cooldownTime)/1000;
        if(cooldownTime < interval) {
            return message.channel.send(`gotta wait ${timeToWait} more seconds`);
        }
      }

      cooldown.set(msg.author.id, Date.now());
      msg.channel.send("heyy");
  }
});
```

If you have any questions, don't hesitate to post a comment!

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm just not too familiar with maps. I did some researching on maps on MDN but its not that clear. I would really appreciate it if you can maybe explain a little about maps. Thanks!

Comment: Map is used to set a value to a key. As shown in my answer, you can use Map.set("ID", data) and Map.get("ID") to get the data. It's useful in your case, to link a user ID to a cooldown time.

Comment: Ooh.. I see, thank you so much for the explanation!